# In Excel, how do I get information in one cell (separated by commas) split into their own cells but in the correct column?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have this information (each is on its own row, but in the same cell column):

```
A, B, C, D
A, C, D
A, D
B, C, D
```

I want it to look like this (in separated columns, labeled "A" "B" "C" "D"):

```
A  B  C  D (<column header row)
A  B  C  D
A     C  D
A        D
   B  C  D
```

Hopefully my illustration makes sense.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

use the text to column feature of Excel 2010.  The feature is located under the data ribbon -->  Data Tools --> Text to Columns.

Highlight the data, select the feature and walk through the screens.  Here are the screen shots.[image: Location of Text to Columns feature in Excel 2010 Ribbon]

[image: Text to Columns Screen Shot 1]

[image: Text to Columns Screen Shot 2]

[image: Text to Columns Screen Shot 3]